# Laravel 5 authentication error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

When i hit `localhost/laravel/public` the url change to `localhost/laravel/public/auth/loin`, And it throws the following error.
`NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 143:`

In my `routes.php` i have:

```
Route::get('/index', ['middleware' => 'auth', function(){
    return view('index');
}]);
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi, your question is not very clear. Can you post more samples ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own Question !

In `project/app/http/middleware/authenticate` . I had a line for redirection if some one is directly accessing a restricted page return redirect()->guest('auth/login'); . So i just removed the auth/login to /login.

Answer (score 0):

For `localhost/laravel/public`
Try

```
Route::get('/', ['middleware' => 'auth', function(){
    return view('index');
}]);
```

your route will work for `localhost/laravel/public/index`

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! 
When i hit the valid credentials it goes from `http://localhost/laravel/public/` to  `http://localhost/laravel/public/auth/login` and error is the same  `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 143:`

Comment: handle redirection in controller after successful login redirect to some other page redirect()->intended('/');

Comment: Buddy i haven't created any middleware . Is it okay ?

Comment: Authentication middleware  is already there in laravel 5.1
check in project/app/http/middleware

Comment: My bad. In ` project/app/http/middleware/authenticate` . I had a line for redirection if some one is directly accessing a restricted page `return redirect()->guest('auth/login');` . So i just removed the `auth/login` to `/login`.